# NUnit how to pass some tests

Tags: .net, selenium, nunit

I've a problem with my selenium2 solution + NUnit.

I've made few `[Test]` functions in my code and I have factorize some recurrents tests.

My problem is, when I launch automatically my test on Debug (`/run`) all unique test are lauched.
So my factorized test just lauch out of context (without instance or parameters...)

[image: Here is the result in NUnit]

Is there any solution to to define this tests as "Can only be launch manually from code ?"
My open to all best practice.

Thanks :D

Comment: Why don't you remove [Test] from your methods you don't want to be run?

Comment: Will they be 'normally' run if I call them from another test method ?

Comment: If you're referring to something like 'new RefactorClass().SomeCommonMethod()' then yeah, they should run.